# Consultar 2 tablas de 2 base de datos con linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

He echo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT *
from ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT INNER JOIN 
Cotizador.dbo.Clientes ON Cotizador.dbo.Clientes.NumeroCliente=ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT.NumeroCliente where ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT.OT = '2'
```

y si me retorna los datos, pero no he podido consultarlo con linq y tengo dudas de como realizarlo,

La tabla alojada en base de datos de ProductoTerminado, llamada OrdenesPT su estructura es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla alojada en base de datos de Cotizador,, llamada Clientes su estructura es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el proyecto en C#, solo tengo declarado la base de datos ProductoTerminado que es donde contiene la tabla OrdenesPT

Comment: Ponme la estructura de las tablas

Comment: Si, de la tabla OrdenesPT es esta: SELECT TOP (1000) [OT]
      ,[Pedido]
      ,[Posicion]
      ,[Sociedad]
      ,[NumeroCliente]
      ,[Cliente]
      ,[Pieza]
      ,[CodigoMaterial]
      ,[Producto]
      ,[Cantidad]
      ,[Importe]
      ,[Fecha]
      ,[Salida]
      ,[SalidaEmp]
      ,[FechaSalidaEmp]
  FROM [ProductoTerminado].[dbo].[OrdenesPT], esta alojada en la primera base de datos y es la primer tabla

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y ponme el diagrama en tu pregunta

Comment: Si esta bien, ahorita la pongo

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer un join o un include:

var query = await _context.OrdenesPT
.Include(x=> x.Clientes).ToListAsync();

O

```
var query = await _context.OrdenesPT.Join(_context.Clientes, o => o.Id,
                                                             c => c.Id,
                                                             (o,c)=> new {
                                                              OrdenesPT = o,
                                                              Clientes = c
                                                              }).ToListAsync();
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Saludos!

Comment: No me resulto ninguna de las 2 :(